# get URL parameter in function based view

Tags: django, django-views

I want to add URL parameter in function based view how can I do?

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/xxxxx/4
```

parameter is 4 I want to aces 4 in view. there is any way to do this?

Comment: pass in fuction call like **`def home(request, pk):`**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
self.kwargs['blog_ID']
```

or

```
def blogpost(request,blog_ID):
```

Answer (score 7):

in **`Function-Based Views:`**

`def Homepage(request, pk):`

**`In class-based views`**

`self.kwargs['pk']`

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#example).

The solution for your example looks like this.

`urls.py`

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('xxxx/<int:your_number>/', views.your_view_name),
]
```

`views.py`

```py
def your_view_name(request, your_number):
    # do things with your_number here.
    # if your_number is optional, define a default
    return render(...)
```